# How to change Plack Session's name?

Tags: perl, plack

I have two applications on the same domain, but they are both creating a plack_session every time the user logs in. It happens because application A overwrites application B's plack session.

It's a complex process to remove one of them and make them use one that is created by a central application, but for now, how can I change one of those 'plack_session' names to something like 'plack_session2' so they don't see each other?

I don't even know if it is possible.

Here is the [document](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Session::State) for Plack Session, but I can't see anything that can help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the documentation you link to, the Plack session middleware is enabled with code like this:

```
builder {
    enable 'Session',
        state => Plack::Session::State->new;
    $app;
};
```

Later in the same document, you'll find the documentation for the `new()` method:

> **new ( %params )**
>
> The `%params` can include *session_key*, *sid_generator* and *sid_checker* however in both cases a default will be provided for you.
>
> **session_key**
>
> This is the name of the session key, it defaults to 'plack_session'.
>
> ...

Putting all this together, I'd guess (and I haven't ever done this) that you can do what you want with code like this:

```
builder {
    enable 'Session',
        state => Plack::Session::State->new(
          session_key => 'my_session_key',
        );
    $app;
};
```

Comment: Dave Cross thanks, it worked with: Plack::Session::State::Cookie -> new(
          session_key => 'my_session_key',
        );